# When I submit my data to the text field it is not submitting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my Postcontroller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($id)
    {

        return "It's working".$id;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request   $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        return $request->all();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        return "Show Controller ".$id;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function contact(){
        $people=['Snehal','Swarna','Rhitu','Mashuk','Sajid'];
        return view('contact',compact('people'));
    }
    public function show_post($id,$name,$password){
        return view('post',compact('id','name','password'));
    }
}
```

myroute https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLr0b.jpg

My Create view https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfIft.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO .... please do not put up pictures of code, just copy your code and paste it into a code block in your question, thanks :)

Comment: You mean your request object has no title?

Answer (score 0):

For your form action, it's suggested to use route() function, like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using resource for `/posts`. You should rewrite the action form to Ahmad Karimi's answer.

Additionally, you can use `dd($request->all());` to see if your form field is submitting to the controller.